# emailjs not working [node js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, web, smtp

i'm trying to use the emailjs (https://github.com/eleith/emailjs) for send emails with nodejs, but, it gives me an error: { [Error: timedout while connecting to smtp server] code: 4, smtp: undefined }

I'm trying to use hotmail, but I can use other, I only want this working. Any idea please?

```
 var email   = require("emailjs");
    var server  = email.server.connect({
       user:    "xxx@hotmail.com", 
       password:"xxxyyyy", 
       host:    "smtp-mail.live.com", 
       ssl:     true
    });

    // send the message and get a callback with an error or details of the message that was sent
    server.send({
       text:    "i hope this works", 
       from:    "you <xxxxxx@hotmail.com>", 
       to:      "someone <zzzzz@hotmail.com>",
       //cc:      "else <else@your-email.com>",
       subject: "testing emailjs"
    }, function(err, message) { console.log(err || message); });
```

Comment: The error suggests it is a simple connection information error, or a problem with your network, neither of which we can help much with unless you also provided the server connection information that you were given for the mailserver (without creds of course)

Comment: See here: https://github.com/eleith/emailjs#example-usage---sending-through-hotmailoutlook are you sure you need ssl, and not tls?

Comment: This code of the link not works too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested with the code below (using gmail) and it is working:

```
var email = require('emailjs');

var server = email.server.connect({
  user: 'nodejsiscool@gmail.com',
  password: 'stackoverflow',
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  ssl: true
});

server.send({
  text: 'Hey howdy',
  from: 'NodeJS',
  to: 'Wilson <wilson.balderrama@gmail.com>',
  cc: '',
  subject: 'Greetings'
}, function (err, message) {
  console.log(err || message);
});
```

In my console the output is:

```
{ 
  attachments: [],
  alternative: null,
  header: { 
    'message-id': '<1433256538447.0.5970@Wilsons-MacBook-Pro.local>',
    date: 'Tue, 02 Jun 2015 10:48:58 -0400',
    from: '=?UTF-8?Q?NodeJS?= <>',
    to: '=?UTF-8?Q?Wilson?= <wilson.balderrama@gmail.com>',
    cc: '',
    subject: '=?UTF-8?Q?Greetings?=' 
 },
 content: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
 text: 'Hey howdy' 
}
```

Indeed I have received in my inbox the email message.

I suspect that you should use the host **smtp.live.com** instead of **smtp-mail.live.com**

Note: The account (nodejsiscool@gmail.com) used is a valid one I just created for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

**Using Gmail**

**First**: Required activate the use less secure apps at your own risk as indicated in the Gmail documentation. I use an account not very important for my tests:

https://myaccount.google.com/u/2/lesssecureapps?pageId=none

**After:**

```
var email   = require("emailjs");
var server  = email.server.connect({
   user:    "YOUR_ACCOUNT@gmail.com", 
   password:"YOUR_PASSWORD", 
   host:    "smtp.gmail.com",
   ssl:     true
});

server.send({
   text:    "Hello world", 
   from:    "YOUR_NAME <YOUR_ACCOUNT@gmail.com>", 
   to:      "FRIEND_NAME <FRIEND_ACCOUNT@gmail.com>",
   subject: "Hello"
}, function(err, message) { console.log(err || message); });
```

---

**Additional Note:** About how set "from" and displayed name in Gmail inbox:

Example 1:

Set "from" with only name.

```
from:    "YOUR_NAME", // Only name
```

In inbox display <>

```
YOUR_NAME <>                 Hello                                  18:11
```

Example 2:

Set "from" with name and emial.

```
from:    "YOUR_NAME <YOUR_ACCOUNT@gmail.com>", // Name and email
```

In inbox not display <>

```
YOUR_NAME                    Hello                                  18:11
```

Comment: Hello I have activated the use less secure app but I am facing an error like

`ERROR TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
at Object../node_modules/emailjs/smtp/message.js
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are linking the emailjs files correctly (check var email) or it won't work.

```
//Email stuff
var email   = require("./node_modules/emailjs/email");
var server  = email.server.connect({
   user:    "EMAIL@gmail.com",
   password:"INSERTPASSWORDHERE",
   host:    "smtp.gmail.com",
   ssl:     true
});

//If button is clicked then send email
    server.send({
      text: 'Hello World! \n\n Regards,\n INSERTNAMEHERE \n',
      from: 'Name',
      to: 'Name <EMAIL@gmail.com>',
      cc: '',
      subject: ''
    }, function (err, message) {
      console.log(err || message);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have installed exact package with same version

```
 npm i emailjs@1.0.11
```

and try below code

```
var email = require("emailjs");
var server = email.server.connect({
user: "your-email@gmail.com",
password: "your-password",
host: "smtp.gmail.com",
ssl: true
});

server.send(
{
text: "Hey howdy",
from: "NodeJS",
to: "Wilson <your-email@gmail.com>",
cc: "",
subject: "Greetings"
},
function(err, message) {
 console.log(err || message);
}
);
```

seems latest version is not working its using es6 exports "emailjs@1.0.11" but version still works fine .
also don't forget to enable [less secure](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) setting for email address you are using with password .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this version

> emailjs@2.2.0

,
For me, this is working in version 2.2.0
where version 3.0 and above will show the error.

```
npm i emailjs@2.2.0
```

[here is the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSqOh.png)